# Necessary and sufficient condition when two cycles in $S_{n}$ conjugate

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, permutations

I need to find and prove a necessary and sufficient condition when two cycles $x=(x_{1}x_{2}\cdots x_{m})$ and $y=(y_{1}y_{2}\cdots y_{t})$ in a permutation group $S_{n}$ are conjugate.

My idea was that two cycles $x=(x_{1}x_{2}\cdots x_{m})$ and $y = (y_{1}y_{2}\cdots y_{t})$ in $S_{n}$ are conjugate if and only if the cycles are of the same length (i.e., $m=t$) and $\exists f \in S_{n}$ such that $\forall x_{i}$, $f(y_{i}) = x_{i}$.

Here's my attempt at a proof:

> $(\implies)$ Suppose $x = (x_{1} x_{2} \cdots x_{m})$ and $y = (y_{1}y_{2}\cdots y_{t})$ in $S_{n}$ are conjugate. Then $\exists f \in S_{n}$ such that $ f y f^{-1} = x \\ \implies \, f(y_{1} y_{2} \cdots y_{t})f^{-1}=(x_{1}x_{2}\cdots x_{m}) \\ \implies \, (f(y_{1})f(y_{2})\cdots f(y_{t})) = (x_{1},x_{2},\cdots, x_{m})$.
>
> So, $f(y_{1})=x_{1}$, $f(y_{2})=x_{2}, \cdots , f(y_{t})=x_{m} \, \implies \, t = m$.
>
> $(\Longleftarrow)$ Suppose $x=(x_{1}x_{2}\cdots x_{m})$ and $y = (y_{1}y_{2}\cdots y_{t})$ in $S_{n}$ are of the same length (i.e., $m = t$) and suppose also that $\exists f \in S_{n}$ such that $\forall i, f(y_{i}) = x_{i}$.
>
> Then, we must have that $(f(y_{1})f(y_{2})\cdots f(y_{t})) = (x_{1}x_{2} \cdots x_{m}) \, \implies \, f(y_{1}y_{2}\cdots y_{t})f^{-1} = (x_{1}x_{2},\cdots, x_{m}) \, \implies \, x$ and $y$ are conjugate.

I doubt that this is true, but I made a bonafide attempt. If it's not true, could somebody please tell me what is a necessary and sufficient condition for two cycles to be conjugate and steer me in the direction of how to prove it?

I do know that in $S_{n}$, two permutations are conjugate iff they are of the same cycle type. And, in fact, that's next on my list of things I have to prove.

Thanks.

Comment: "two permutations are conjugate iff they are of the same cycle type" - this of course holds for cycles as well (cycles being permutations), and two cycles have the same cycle type precisely if they are of the same length. Your second condition is vacuous: such $f$ always exists (provided that the length of the two cycles are the same).

Comment: @relep so if I minimize the second condition, it's good?

Comment: You do need to be assuming that the $x_i$s are all distinct, and similarly for the $y_i$s. But when you call them cycles, I'm assuming you understand that.

Comment: What you are doing is in fact "relabel" your entries. This can even be done step-wise by conjugating by two-cycles (a,b)*(...)*(a,b) will interchange a and b in the cycle, if both were presenet, or replace a with b (only if a was present). Beware, this works in symmteric groups. In the alternating group $A_6$ the cycles $(1,2,3,4,5)$ and $(1,2,3,4,6)$ are **not** conjugate.

Comment: @relep, in my $(\Longleftarrow)$ part, I realize that it's that case that if $f \in S_{n}$ is any permutation, then $fyf^{-1} = (f(y_{1}f(y_{2}) \cdots f(y_{t}))$, but how am I able to then say that $(f(y_{1})f(y_{2}) \cdots f(y_{t})) = (x_{1}x_{2} \cdots x_{m})$ necessarily solely on the assumption that $x$ and $y$ are the same length?

Comment: @TedShifrin please feel free to shed some light on this, too (not the same thing I tagged you about earlier).

Comment: I honestly can't follow what you're confused about here. Suppose we want to conjugate $(12)$ to get $(13)$. We consider the permutation $f$ that leaves $1$ along and sends $2$ to $3$. Then $f(12)f^{-1} = (23)(12)(32) = (13)$. It's like the change-of-basis formula in linear algebra (indeed you can do this with permutation matrices).  In general,  you choose any permutation $f$ that sends $y_i$ to $x_i$ and the same thing works.